# Sharepoint 2010 External Content Type list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm taking my first crack at creating an External list in Sharepoint 2010. I've taken 3 training classes in Sharepoint 2010, and am now trying to transfer my knowledge to my own development environment. I've followed the steps for creating my External Content type in Micorosoft sharepoint designer. I am connecting the External Content Type to a table in an external SQL Server Database. I've created a list specifying this External Content type. I've also given all authenticated users permission. I've verified that BCS is running, and all looks good. I've also checked and double checked the steps I used in creating the external content type and list, by referring to the lab manual from my Sharepoint class.

When I try to navigate to display the list, I get this very informative error message:

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Correlation ID:b7c91266-bbbc-4703-8704-beccbbd92de0

I've tried opening this page in Sharepoint Designer but this doesn't seem to help me. Has anyone experienced this problem before? Any gotcha's that I should be looking for.

Comment: This would be more appropriate on the SharePoint site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see a correlation ID, then you should be able to get more information on the failure in the [ULS output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512738.aspx).  Search for that Correlation ID in the logs and you should get plenty of additional information.

If you don't find much in the ULS logs, then change the settings to log additional information.

Comment: I did a search on the logs in c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS for the correlation ID that I was given, and did not find any matches. Where do I modify the settings to log more information.

Comment: Here's one link among many that shows how to modify what is logged. Be careful: you can use a lot of disk space quickly:  http://sharepointstudy.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/uls-logging-%E2%80%93-part-1/

Comment: I turned on all details, brought up the list again which received the same error. I repeated my search on the log files and still received no results. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check selection of primary key of sql tables while retrieving data to list.

Comment: Can you clarify this for me? I have created my external content type and specified the primary key. I am doing this from SharePoint Designer. I see that the primary key is listed in the key information section. I then click the Create Lists & Form from the ribbon which I use to create the list. I don't see where I can specify to check selection of primary key of sql tables. Where am I missing this?

If I open Read List.aspx in advanced mode in Sharepoint Designer, I get: error: soap:ServerException of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.An error has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the error being thrown, use the SharePoint LogViewer app from CodePlex:  http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

1. You need to run it on your server and hit the Play Button at the
   top.  This starts the Live Monitoring.
2. Refresh your page that will give you the error with the Correlation ID.
3. Stop The LogViewer and filter the results by the Correlation Field.
4. Copy and paste the ID from your browser into the filter field.
5. You will now see a list of what errors are being thrown in relation to the Correlation ID.

I hope this helps out!